# Alfresco When i call trigger.js locate at Repository > Data Dictionary > Scripts >trigger.js using ajax call, its not executing workflow

Tags: javascript, alfresco

When i call trigger.js locate at Repository >  Data Dictionary >  Scripts >trigger.js using ajax call, its just calling the trigger.js file but not executing workflow

trigger.js file code below:

```
var workflow = actions.create("start-workflow");
workflow.parameters.workflowName = "activiti$TrainerEmpanelment";
workflow.parameters["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("admin");
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDescription"] = "Trainer request";
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowPriority"] = "2";
workflow.parameters["bpm:sendEMailNotifications"] = true;
workflow.parameters["initiator"] = people.getPerson("admin"); 
var today = new Date();
var duedate = today.getDate() + 1; 
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDueDate"] = duedate;
workflow.execute(document);
```

Ajax code below,

```
var me = this;
var actionUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/page/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/9bab7364-5417-4835-ad2b-6d6a971b4493";
alert(actionUrl);   
Alfresco.util.Ajax.request({
   url: actionUrl,
   method: Alfresco.util.Ajax.GET,
   responseContentType: Alfresco.util.Ajax.JSON,
   successCallback:{
       fn: function(res){   
           alert("This alert is  triggered");
       },
       scope: me
   },
   failureCallback:{
       fn: me.__failureHandler,
       scope: me
   },
   scope: me,
   noReloadOnAuthFailure: me
});
```

How can i execute the worflow using ajax call?

Comment: Call it as a webscript? Call it via the JS console? Call it via a Rule?

Comment: I am calling it as a webscript

Comment: Your client side javascript seems to be calling a document details page, not a webscript!

Comment: could you suggest me how can i trigger workflow 1 to workflow2 is this possible without using ruling

Comment: There's at least half a dozen ways! You need to be more specific on what you're trying to do, and especially on where you want to trigger the new workflow from (eg do you want one workflow to start another during a transition, or do it client side, or something else)

Comment: In Workflow 1 ,workflow form have check box if checked check box workflow 2 will trigger ,i want trigger from client side JS code is this poissible? suggest me with reference

Comment: Why trigger it from client side JS? What happens if someone checks the box, then unchecks it? Wouldn't you be much better off doing the checking and launching on the server side, once the form is submitted and once you know for sure what the user's final choice is? (Also it's much easier to launch a new workflow from the server!)

Comment: your solution is the one which i am looking for, Can you please suggest me how do it from server side

Answer (score 0):

You can call your repo webscript using AJAX like this

```
 var mylink=encodeURI("/webscript-url?parameter1="+value1);

                    Alfresco.util.Ajax.request({

                              url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + mylink,

                              method: Alfresco.util.Ajax.GET,

                    });
```

Place this code in your repo webscript's JS file and Change the required properties according to your requirement.

```
function startWorkflow()
{
    var value2 = args["parameter1"];// you can get parameter by this
    var workflowAction = workflow.getDefinitionByName("activiti$test_wf");
    var package= workflow.createPackage();

    var wfparams = new Array();
    wfparams["model_prefix:req_props_name"] = value2;

    wfparams["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("admin");
    workflowAction.startWorkflow(package, wfparams);
    }

}

startWorkflow();
```